# Update Select case with new combobox item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, combobox

i'm trying to update a case when i'm creating a new combobox item, I don't find the way to do that, because I created a Select Case and I only control the Items that are on my program initially.

I've created a StripMenu, and when I click on this Item it puts this "object" on my Combobox, but then I've to tract with it and I don't know the way to do that....

```
Private Sub MonedaToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MonedaToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim NovaMoneda As Object
    NovaMoneda = InputBox("Nueva moneda")
    cbMoneda.Items.Add(NovaMoneda)
End Sub
```

I've Select Case like this, the thing is that it recognises the new object...

```
Select Case (cbMoneda.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            Moneda = "Dolars"
        Case 1
            Moneda = "Yenes"
        Case 2
            Moneda = "Lliures"
        Case 3
            Moneda = "Dragmes"
    End Select
```

Thanks.

EDIT ******

I have included the Select Case to help you to understand my issue... Now with your help I can only create 1 currency more...

```
Private Sub btIgual_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btIgual.Click
    Dim MonedaEscollida As String
    MonedaEscollida = QuinaMonedaVol(MonedaEscollida)
    Select Case MonedaEscollida
        Case "Dolars"
            If Dolar = 0 Then
                tbNumeros.Text = CType(tbNumeros.Text, Double) * PreguntaValorEuros()
            Else
                tbNumeros.Text = tbNumeros.Text * Dolar
            End If
        Case "Yenes"
            If Yen = 0 Then
                tbNumeros.Text = CType(tbNumeros.Text, Double) * PreguntaValorEuros()
            Else
                tbNumeros.Text = tbNumeros.Text * Yen
            End If
        Case "Lliures"
            If Libra = 0 Then
                tbNumeros.Text = CType(tbNumeros.Text, Double) * PreguntaValorEuros()
            Else
                tbNumeros.Text = tbNumeros.Text * Libra
            End If
        Case "Dragmes"
            If Dragma = 0 Then
                tbNumeros.Text = CType(tbNumeros.Text, Double) * PreguntaValorEuros()
            Else
                tbNumeros.Text = tbNumeros.Text * Dragma
            End If
        Case Else
            If ValorIntroduit = 0 Then
                tbNumeros.Text = CType(tbNumeros.Text, Double) * PreguntaValorEuros()
            Else
                tbNumeros.Text = tbNumeros.Text * ValorIntroduit
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Not understand your problem, clearly, Be specific what you want?

Comment: As per my thinking, you want to handle the case where selected index is not in your Case statement

Comment: Maybe you must call combobox.selectedItem because you added a string like a combobox item.

Comment: Please, add the desired behavior.

Comment: Well.. my program is an "euro Calculator", then I just want that user can create a new Currency to let to user exchange euro to new money (it doesn't matter if it doesn't exist, and btw only on running the program, when it closes the combobox keeps with the initially currency), I have a Input Box that asks the user to enter the value of the exchange for 1 € and that's the only thing I know to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the items generated at runtime dynamically. Something like this might work to grab the name of your dynamically generated items.

```
Select Case (cbMoneda.SelectedIndex)
    Case 0
        Moneda = "Dolars"
    Case 1
        Moneda = "Yenes"
    Case 2
        Moneda = "Lliures"
    Case 3
        Moneda = "Dragmes"
    Case Else
        Moneda = cbMoneda.Items(cbMoneda.SelectedIndex).Value.ToString()
End Select
```

Comment: Then why don't you completely remove the Select Case?

Comment: how to control the ComboBox Item?

Comment: @Steve Great point, but right now there is no indication that those values match the strings in the Case.

Comment: @Palim321 You'll have to be more specific about what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the SelectedIndex would can directly get the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Moneda = CStr(cbMoneda.SelectedValue)
```